# Lists inside list, how to access elements?

Tags: r

I have a function that needs to return two two different types of groups of vectors. I could do this using a list consisting of two matrices, where the vectors, that I want to return, correspond to columns in the matrix, but since the vectors all have different lengths, I would like to save the vectors in a list themselves, so that I have a list consisting of two lists.

I would like to add the vectors to the sublists now, but don't know which indices to use.

For example if I would like to add the vector x to the first sublist in my list(call it l), how would I do that?

```
l[[1]] <- x
```

would only replace the first vector in the first sublist, but how could I access the second element in the sublist using indices?

Comment: `l[[1]][[1]] <- x` would replace the first element in the first sub list, `l[[1]][[2]] <- x` the second, etc.

Comment: you also have l[[c(1,2)]] <- x

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I don't want to replace elements in the sublist, I would like to add elements to the sublist. E.g. if I have a vector c(1,2,3) in l[[1]], I want to add another vector c(4,2,3) to l[[1]] without replacing any elements, so that l[[1]] is a list consisting of two vectors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To add elements to sublists, start with the list:

```
l <- list(list(1:3), list(5:8))             
str(l)
```

Which looks like so:

```
List of 2
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ : int [1:3] 1 2 3
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ : int [1:4] 5 6 7 8
```

And add another vector inside a list:

```
l[[1]] <- c(l[[1]], list(100:103))
str(l)
```

Produces:

```
List of 2
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : int [1:3] 1 2 3
  ..$ : int [1:4] 100 101 102 103
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ : int [1:4] 5 6 7 8
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I want. One question though, how can I access e.g. the second vector in the first sublist of l?

Comment: `l[[1]][[2]]` produces `[1] 100 101 102 103`

Comment: A way to make accessing list elements easier is to work with named lists, then you can step down the list hierarchy like so: `l$first_level$second_level$third_level$....`

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand what exactly you mean. But you can use a list containing two lists like this:

```
a=list();
a[[1]]=c(1,2,3);
a[[2]]=c(3,4,5);
a[['key']]=c(5,6,7)
a[[1]][1] //the first element in sublist 1
a[['key']][2] //the second element in sublist 'key'
```

if you want to store two vector, may be a matrix is what you waht

```
a[[1]]=cbind(a[[1]], c(2,3,4))
a[[1]][,1] //the first vector in sublist 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I would like is this: in your example a is a list consisting of two vectors. Now I would like this list to be a sublist of another "higher" list, lets call it l. so that l[[1]] returns your list a. And then I want to know how to add more elements to a while a is inside the list l.

Answer (score 2):

you can made a list of the two vectors :

```
l <- vector("list", 2)
l[[1]] <- 1:3
l[[1]] <- list(l[[1]],2:4)
```

Comment: Note this breaks down if you want to add yet another vector as you end up with as sublist that contains a list, and a vector.  You need to use `c` or `append` with the vector to be appended wrapped in `list`.